# How to Access the Directory API in Admin SDK

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

Trying in vain to access the Directory API in the Google Admin SDK ([Reference](https://google-developers.appspot.com/admin-sdk/directory/)).  Upgrading the "google-api-python-client" package doesn't resolve it, as the Downloads > Installation > Python link instructs.

I also don't see in the documentation where it lists the programmatic name of the API, so I'm assuming it's "directory", but have also tried "directory.admin" and "admin.directory."  I get the following exception when I try to run my test code:

```
apiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: directory  version: v1
```

Could someone please assist with what I may be overlooking?  Unfortunately, the "Quickstart" that provides the shell to access the API seems to be broken ([Reference](https://google-developers.appspot.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started)).  When I select Python > Command-Line > Configure Project, I get an error that states "Sorry, unable to configure a project right now."

Here's the pertinent piece of code I'm using in my custom Directory library class:

```
class Directory(object):
    def __init__(self, httpConnection):
        self.service = build('directory', 'v1', http=httpConnection)
```

Is this just a case of no client library being available yet for the API?  If so, when might that be available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an issue where this new API isn't appearing in the list of supported APIs, but it is indeed there, you can access it from:

```
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1')
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe!  That did the trick.  (Just needed to add the Customer ID to get the Users list() API call to work.)